# Create generic class that counts average value of numeric T

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I need create a class

```
Average<T>
```

that contains 3 methods:

- T average() - returns average value of collection of T values;
- add(T item) - adds item to collection of T values
- reset() - resets Average instance to its default state

T must be a numeric (int, float, byte etc.)

As I understand right I have to create base abstract class or interface:

```
public abstract class NumericBase<T>{}
```

which my derived classes inherit:

```
public class NumericInt:NumericBase<int>{}
```

After that I should create my Average class:

```
public class Average<T> where T: NumericBase<T>
```

But I guess last step is wrong because I must create method add(T item) inside Average class, and if I understand this task correctly it must works like this:

```
Average<int> av = new Average();
av.add(3);
av.add(4);
int averageValue = av.average();
av.reset();
```

I’ve been trying to solve this problem all day, and so I haven’t achieved anything. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There is no such a generic constraint for numbers. I'm not sure you really need to use generic type, but if for learning purpose you want to just play with generics and `Enumerable` methods, you can check the type of `T` in constructor and if it's not one of the allowed types (for example int and double) then throw an exception.

Comment: I've tried to use derived classes for each type I need and override abstract property ValueList that contains all T items added, I've tried to create ItemType property that initializes by constructor of my abstract NumericBase class to use it in Add function as parameter type.

Comment: Having the abstract base class doesn't change what is mentioned in the first comment. Just for learning purpose, as an example, I shared an answer.

Comment: Thank you. But the task was formulated in this way. It's not my decision to use generics in this task.

Comment: Why would the `average` return value be an `int`? Integers are not closed under division, having `average` return `T` is weird.

Comment: @DmitryL No problem. Hope you get the point. Basically all the answers are suggesting multiple classes as far as I see. So make sure you read the bluet points in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint is wrong, there's no way to have `T : NumericBase<T>`, it'd be an infinitely recursive type.

Unfortunately, C# does not have a generic constraint for a "numeric" type, something that would allow you to add instances of `T` together or divide them by a number. You cannot express a constraint that "this is a number", but there is a way to constraint `T` to be *convertible* to a number (and a bunch of other types).

```cs
public class Average<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        double converted = item.ToDouble(null); 
        ...
    }
}
```

That way you constrain yourself to double precision floating-point and anyone trying to use that class with a custom type would have to implement the entire [`IConvertible` interface, which is pretty big](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=netstandard-2.1#notes-to-implementers). I'm not sure that it's how that interface was intended to be used, but what the heck.

There's hardly any other way of doing this without dropping your requirement that `int` is a correct argument for `T`. If we do drop that, then a whole world of possibilities opens up:

```cs
public interface IAverageable<TValue, TAverage>
{
    TValue AddTogether(TValue other);
    TAverage DivideByCount(int count);
}

public struct AverageableInt : IAverageable<AverageableInt, double>
{
    private readonly int _n;

    public AverageableInt(int n) => _n = n;

    public AverageableInt AddTogether(AverageableInt other) =>
        new AverageableInt(this._n + other._n);

    public double DivideByCount(int count) => (double)_n / count;
}

public class Average<TValue, TAverage> where TValue : IAverageable<TValue, TAverage>
{
   ... // Implementation.
}
```

```cs
var average = new Average<AverageableInt, double>();

average.Add(new AverageableInt(3));
average.Add(new AverageableInt(4));
...
```

You can make it a bit neater by introducing a user-defined conversion between `int` and `AverageableInt`:

```cs
// Inside AverageableInt.
    public static implicit operator AverageableInt(int n) => new AverageableInt(n);
```

```cs
var average = new Average<AverageableInt, double>();

average.Add(3);
average.Add(4);
...
```

It will require you to add a lot of custom types to make it work with every built-in type, but it's a working, type-safe solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following points:

- There is no such a generic constraint for numbers.
- When you think of a generic constraint which is limited to 2-3 types, it usually means you don't need generic types, instead you need to create 2-3 different classes.

I'm not sure you really need to use generic type, but if for learning purpose you want to just play with generics, list, and Enumerable class methods, you can check the type of `T` in constructor and if it's not one of the allowed types (for example int and double) then throw an exception.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public sealed class MyBadClass<T>
{
    List<T> list;
    public MyBadClass()
    {
        var allowedTypes = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(double), typeof(float) };
        if (!allowedTypes.Contains(typeof(T)))
            throw new Exception($"Type '{typeof(T)}' not supported.");
        list = new List<T>();
    }
    public double Average()
    {
        return list.Cast<double>().Average();
    }
    public void Add(T value)
    {
        list.Add(value);
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        list.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the second bullet, simply because conceptually you don't want to constrict yourself to 2-3 types, you want to constraint it to all types that satisfy a certain contract, namely that they can be summed together and divided by a number. It's not syntactically expressible in C#, but other languages do have numeric constraints and it's pretty useful.

Comment: @V0ldek Speaking general, I also like to have a numeric generic constraint or having some generic constraints combined with `OR`, .., but the answer is a C#-specific and while C# doesn't allow you to have such generic constraints, I'd say the second point is a valid in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Note that constraining `T` to a numeric type is impossible, and that naming a class the same as a property `Average` isn't allowed. So I name my classes `Statistics`.

You need a non-generic class to act as a factory in order to simplify the instantiation of the derived classes. So instead of `new Statistics<int>.IntStatistics();` you call `Statistics.Int();`

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // start integer statistics
        var int_ave = Statistics.Int();
        int_ave.Add(3);
        int_ave.Add(5);
        int_ave.Add(7);

        Debug.Assert(int_ave.Count == 3);
        Debug.Assert(int_ave.Average == (3+5+7)/3);

        // start float statistics
        var float_ave = Statistics.Float();
        float_ave.AddRange(2f, 4f, 7f, 9f);
        Debug.Assert(float_ave.Count == 4);
        Debug.Assert(float_ave.Average == (2f+4f+7f+9f)/4);
    }

}
/// <summary>
/// Factory
/// </summary>
public static class Statistics
{
    public static Statistics<byte> Byte() => new Statistics<byte>.ByteStatistics();
    public static Statistics<int> Int() => new Statistics<int>.IntStatistics();
    public static Statistics<float> Float() => new Statistics<float>.FloatStatistics();
    public static Statistics<double> Double() => new Statistics<double>.DoubleStatistics();
    public static Statistics<decimal> Decimal() => new Statistics<decimal>.DecimalStatistics();
}
/// <summary>
/// Base class
/// </summary>
public abstract class Statistics<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    public T Average { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When overidden in derived classes the item is considered
    /// and a new average is computed. <see cref="Count"/> is 
    /// also incremented.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The numeric value to add.</param>
    public abstract void Add(T item);

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds multiple values
    /// </summary>
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        foreach (var x in list)
        {
            Add(x);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds multiple values
    /// </summary>
    public void AddRange(params T[] list)
    {
        AddRange(list.AsEnumerable());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the statistics.
    /// </summary>
    public void Reset()
    {
        this.Average = default(T);
        this.Count = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Derived class for byte
    /// </summary>
    internal class ByteStatistics : Statistics<byte>
    {
        public override void Add(byte item)
        {
            Average = (byte)((Count*Average + item)/(Count+1) % 256);
            Count += 1;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Derived class for int
    /// </summary>
    internal class IntStatistics : Statistics<int>
    {
        public override void Add(int item)
        {
            Average = (Count*Average + item)/(Count+1);
            Count += 1;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Derived class for float
    /// </summary>
    internal class FloatStatistics : Statistics<float>
    {
        public override void Add(float item)
        {
            Average = (Count*Average + item)/(Count+1);
            Count += 1;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Derived class for double
    /// </summary>
    internal class DoubleStatistics : Statistics<double>
    {
        public override void Add(double item)
        {
            Average = (Count*Average + item)/(Count+1);
            Count += 1;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Derived class for decimal
    /// </summary>
    internal class DecimalStatistics : Statistics<decimal>
    {
        public override void Add(decimal item)
        {
            Average = (Count*Average + item)/(Count+1);
            Count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

It should be fairly simple to implement `Max` and `Min` properties since each `T` must implement `IComparable<T>` which checks which value is smaller or bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having a syntax error. You are missing the generic constraint that is supposed to be after the "where T" statement.

Instead of this: `public class Average<T> where T: NumericBase<T>`,
Try this: `public class Average<T> where T: struct, NumericBase<T>`

The struct there serves as a constraint for the generic type. Follow this link for details [C#: Constraints in Generics](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/constraints-in-generic-csharp)

Comment: The generic constraint is there - `T` is being constrained to be or derive from `NumericBase<T>`. It's a pretty useless constraint, since no type can actually satisfy it, but it's syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 7 has added support for [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math), i.e. every number type now has interfaces which expose all kinds of mathematical operations.

A generic average can then by implemented by:

```cs
public static T Average<T>(IEnumerable<T> numbers) where T : INumberBase<T>
{
  int count = 0;
  T sum = T.Zero;
  foreach (var item in numbers)
  {
    checked { sum += item; }
    count++;
  }
  
  return sum / T.CreateChecked(count);
}
```

```cs
public void Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine(Average(new float[] { 3, 4 }));   // returns 3.5
  Console.WriteLine(Average(new double[] { 3, 4 }));  // returns 3.5
  Console.WriteLine(Average(new decimal[] { 3, 4 })); // returns 3.5
  Console.WriteLine(Average(new int[] { 3, 4 }));     // returns 3
}
```